# BeautifulSoup find on class doesn't work

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

Printing the text out to the console gives me

```
    <html>
     <body>
      <p>
       }"
      </p>
      <div class='\"message-container\"' id='\"m154862032\"' >
      ...
```

but when I try to extract the message-container div I get an empty list

```
  messageContainers = BeautifulSoup(post).findAll('div',attrs={'class':'message-container'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is badly formed and contains embedded backslashes and quotes in the attribute values. You'll have to include those quotes when searching for the class:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = r'''
...     <html>
...      <body>
...       <p>
...        }"
...       </p>
...       <div class='\"message-container\"' id='\"m154862032\"' >
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.find_all('div', class_=r'\"message-container\"')
[<div class='\"message-container\"' id='\"m154862032\"'>
</div>]
```

I used raw string literals here (`r'...'`) to avoid backslashes being interpreted as escape sequences; that way I don't have to double them.

Comment: this put me toward the right track. your example did work through the console, but wasn't working for me in code. I figured the solution out to be messageContainers = messageContainers.findAll('div',class_='\\"message-container\\"')

Comment: @tareqx3: right, my mistake; I should have cottoned on that the setup would require double escaping or a raw string. Will update the answer for future visitors.